# reuse of views in django

Tags: django, django-views, one-time-password

I am creating a django site where I use an OTP (one time password) to validate user data when logging in. So I have a view in which I manage the login and one that emails the otp, provides the form, checks that the otp is correct and redirects the user to the homepage. Now I would like to reuse the otp view in other situations as well (e.g. password change or recovery). How can I use a view as if it were a normal function, in the sense of calling it from within another view, rendering a template and returning a value to the calling view? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a decorator. E.g. the `@login_required` decorator you may have used is backed by [`user_passes_test()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fb93363c499334d48aa95d40842795be5997817e/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L10-L35); your `@otp_required` decorator could have more logic and only defer to the original view function once your OTP magic passes.

Something like this, as semi-pseudocode. There's no special magic to it, really – the view function decorator simply wraps the view, so it can do whatever a view can.

```
from functools import wraps


class OtpView(views.FormView):
    pass


def requires_otp(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not has_valid_otp_for_request(request):
            return OtpView.as_view()(request)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view

# ...

@requires_otp
def my_view(...):
   pass

# or for CBVs:

... requires_otp(MyView.as_view()) ...
```

Comment: thanks, it might be the one for me. Would you have any references (I have no idea how to create custom decorators) to guides, tutorials or documentation? I found something by searching the web but nothing about decorators "pre-rendering" templates.

Comment: I added an edit. There's really no magic to it – whatever you return from the decorator essentially replaces the original view function in Django's eyes, so you can do whatever you like in it.

Comment: I ran into a problem with this solution. The decorator runs on each iteration of the view, so if, for example, I'm wrong to fill out a form, the decorator runs again when I submit. I would need it only done the first time.

Comment: Store a flag in e.g. `request.session` or the Django cache to figure out whether the view is validated.